# HighStock change tickPositions for Axis dynamically

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to dynamically change [tickPositions](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickPositions) array and redraw the Axis?

Answer (score 3):

You can use tickPositioner function which allows to define dynamic ticks positions.

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickPositioner